# ObservableCollection not always updating UI and variable change incorrectly

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, user-interface

I have the following ViewModel and in my code link this to an items control. However when I use a line such as:

```
onOffSchedule.dc.schedules[0].days[0].data[0] = 9;
```

it only updates the UI sometimes?? And when it does it updates the data all wrong. Instead of assign the first schedule, the first day, and first time slot to 9. It updates the first schedule (for all days??) for the first time slot.

So I am trying to figure out why it updates every index in the days array instead of just the first one.

Thanks in advance!

```
public class ScheduleVM
{
    public ObservableCollection<Schedule> schedules { get; set; }

    private static ScheduleVM viewModel = null;

    public static ScheduleVM getInstance()
    {
        if (viewModel == null)
            viewModel = new ScheduleVM();

        return viewModel;
    }

    private ScheduleVM()
    {
        schedules = new ObservableCollection<Schedule>();

        for (byte i = 0; i < 32; i++)
            schedules.Add(new Schedule());
    }
}

public class Schedule
{
    public ObservableCollection<Day> days { get; set; }

    public Schedule()
    {
        days = new ObservableCollection<Day>();

        int[] values = new int[96];

        for (byte i = 0; i < 96; i++)
            values[i] = 3;

        for (byte i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            days.Add(new Day() { data = values });
    }
}

public class Day : BaseVM
{
    private int[] _data;
    public int[] data
    {
        get
        {
            return _data;
        }
        set
        {
            _data = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("data");
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the view that goes along with this code. It is a user control that I create inside another window (and inside that window the user control is called 'onOffSchedule'.

```
public ScheduleVM dc { get; private set; }

    public Schedule()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        dc = ScheduleVM.getInstance();
        this.DataContext = dc;

        schedule.ItemsSource = dc.schedules[0].days;
    }
```

Comment: For this line:    days.Add(new Day() { data = values });  Are all the days supposed to be sharing the same values?  Or should each day get its *OWN* set of values?

Comment: Yep they should have each had their own memory allocation. That explains the other bug I was having. Thank you!

Comment: if you need it fleshed out in an answer, just shout.  But I think you're all sorted on this question

Comment: Absolutely I got it, just an oversight on my part. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
onOffSchedule.dc.schedules[0].days[0].data[0] = 9;
```

That line will not trigger an update under normal circumstances. What you're doing is just setting an integer in an integer array:

```
public int[] data { ... }
```

You put the `OnPropertyChanged` call in there for when the *entire array* changes. But when you just set one of the values, WPF doesn't know that occurred.

You have the right idea by using the `ObservableCollection<Day>` on your other class. You need to do something similar in your `Day` class for the data property.

Comment: Now it updates all the time, but I am still having weird behavior in that when i call onOffSchedule.dc.schedules[0].days[0].data[0] = 9; it updates all 8 indices in the days array to 9

Comment: I have put a breakpoint in and stepped through the code and when it gets the line above it updates the specified index properly but also the same time slot for every other day in the specified schedule

Comment: Is it updating the actual data objects or is it just that the UI is updating incorrectly?

Comment: It was the  data objects (and subsequently UI) being updated but it was because they were all sharing the same array in memory

Answer (score 1):

You're updating an element within the data array. That array does not fire off property changed notifications, so there's no way that the View knows to update itself. Make your data an ObservableCollection and see if it helps.

Comment: When I inherit from the BaseVM it includes a INotifyPropertyChanged handler (that's what the OnPropertyChanged method is). Will that do the same thing?

Comment: As Tim said below, it would only fire when you assign the property, for example `myDay.data = new int[] {};`, but not when you assign individual elements within the data array. When you do that, you are not actually calling the setter for the `data` property